# Strange changed permissions after creating new mac user (vim, idl, etc...)

Tags: macos, vim, permissions, account

I had an account name bally and had to create a new account called jbally because there was something wrong with bally.

This fixed the original issue which is not important but now when I go to save a vim file is says that it's not writable even though the the permissions show -rw----- which match another computer's permissions where vim works on.

any tips?

Thanks,
Max

image one

[image: error one]

image two

[image: error two]

image three

[image: error three]

Comment: does the new account own the file?

Comment: You can't do anything in `/Users/bally/` if you are logged in as `jbally`.

Comment: It would help if you showed the output of `ls -l` on the files in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you probably didn't change the owner of any of the files when you created the new account. You just need to change the owner.

To do this use chown to change the owner to jbally.

```
sudo chown -R jbally /User/bally
```

Comment: I believe I already changed the ownership to the new account. I'll edit the original comment with a couple of screenshots.